# deleting all k8s objects by environment

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

what is the command to remove all objects using kubectl for a specific environment?

kubectl -n squad-mb get all

returns all environments for example, and in order to delete one environment I would like to know how to see it, and which command would be required to delete the specific environment (i.e. develop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kubectl -n namespace delete all pods -l env=dev

Answer (score 10):

To delete all resources of a given namespaces use:

```
kubectl delete all --all -n {my-namespace}
```

Explanation:

- Usage: `kubectl delete ([-f FILENAME] | TYPE [(NAME | -l label | --all)]) [options]`
- **all**: all resources types. If you want to delete only some resources you can do `kubectl delete deployments,pods,replicasets,services --all`
- **--all**: delete all resources of a type (or all types if using *all*). Example: `kubectl delete pods --all`
- **-n**: selects the desired namespace. If empty the command is valid for the [default namespace of your context](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/#setting-the-namespace-preference). You can select all namespaces with *--all-namespaces*

Answer (score 0):

Just re-create the namespace:

```
kubectl delete ns squad-mb
kubectl create ns squad-mb
```

This will recursively delete everything inside.